# achievo migration to new server errror 500

Tags: php, web-services, permissions, project

i had to change my installation of achievo to a new server

and now ia have a 500 error

I have tried everything `chown`, `chmod` ... and nothing work in same server i have `glpi` and `joomla` working at 100% but achievo no. Can someone help? Thanks

```
Warning: require_once(/volume1/web/achievo-145/config.inc.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /volume1/web/achievo-145/atk/include/configs.inc on line 28 
Call Stack: 0.0004 133864 
1. {main}() /volume1/web/achievo-145/index.php:0 0.0005 134240 
2. include_once('/volume1/web/achievo-145/atk.inc') /volume1/web/achievo-145/index.php:7 0.0006 134512 
3. include_once('/volume1/web/achievo-145/atk/include/initial.inc') /volume1/web/achievo-145/atk.inc:15 0.0007 134768 
4. require_once('/volume1/web/achievo-145/atk/include/basics.inc') /volume1/web/achievo-145/atk/include/initial.inc:19 0.0011 136448 
5. require_once('/volume1/web/achievo-145/atk/include/configs.inc') /volume1/web/achievo-145/atk/include/basics.inc:22 

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required './config.inc.php' (include_path='.') in /volume1/web/achievo-145/atk/include/configs.inc on line 28 
Call Stack: 0.0004 133864 
1. {main}() /volume1/web/achievo-145/index.php:0 0.0005 134240 
2. include_once('/volume1/web/achievo-145/atk.inc') /volume1/web/achievo-145/index.php:7 0.0006 134512 
3. include_once('/volume1/web/achievo-145/atk/include/initial.inc') /volume1/web/achievo-145/atk.inc:15 0.0007 134768 
4. require_once('/volume1/web/achievo-145/atk/include/basics.inc') /volume1/web/achievo-145/atk/include/initial.inc:19 0.0011 136448 
5. require_once('/volume1/web/achievo-145/atk/include/configs.inc') /volume1/web/achievo-145/atk/include/basics.inc:22
```

Comment: could you please show which user/group the webserver runs at and which user/group owns the files in question?

Comment: i have tried change onwer and group from admin:users to root:root to http:http ... in this moment is root:root

Comment: well, usually your web server does **not** run as root. if it does, it's configured wrong. most of the time it's either www-data or http. make sure your folder and all its content actually belongs to this user and group with `chown www-data:www-data /your/path -R`

Comment: thanks once again 
the achievo is hosted in a synology dsm216s the user www-data does not exist, i changed again the user to http:http ...joomla, glpi, phpmyadmin ..ok ...achievo ..same error

Answer (score 0):

first question resolved

i was using mariadb10 ...

intalling mariadb5 the access to login form was restored

but now have another error ..halted

Critical: Unknown error: 2002 (Connection refused).
Halted 
error: [+1.31942s / 0.00221s] Unknown error: 2002 (Connection refused)
Halted...

Does anyone could help with this ?

Thanks

Comment: Problem with db connection, using a socket, need to add port to config.inc.php ? where ?
i can login with admin but all the menus give error 2002 and setup give connection error to db thanks

Comment: Posting follow-up requests as answers is not effective at attracting answerers. Read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) for suggestions to get more attention.